# Storing DataSet in Session

Tags: asp.net, session, datatable

I have read a lot about storing datatable/set in session/viewstate and general consensus seems to be that its not a good idea as it slows down the webpage..but it has its advantages..
Now Iam making a website that allows users to create/manage/host quizzes..and I want to retrieve certain number of questions from database(value of questions will be defined) and store it in a datatable which is maintained in session...Max. no of questions should be 120..
So total data to be stored in session = 120 questions + options + correctanswer; along with other minor things like score of candidate and userdata

My question is: Considering maximum number of questions to be 120, will this much data seriously affect the performance of my page, if so then kindly help me by telling an alternative method...thx.

Comment: Why do you need to store 120 questions + options + answers in a session?? Why you just don't store the values in the db and retrieve them when needed? If you have some performance issues, it means you're doing something wrong and using session for storage purposes is always a bad idea. It's meant as a means for storing current state. It's not a data store! Btw, `retrieve certain number of questions from database(value of questions will be defined) and store it in a datatable which is maintained in session` what??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view state is certainly not a good place to store this kind of data as the data set will be serialized into a (very long) string and sent to a client with each request. In general, I'd avoid view state whenever possible (in my opinion it has far more disadvantages than advantages).

Storing the data set in session should be fine as long as you use in-process session mode. In this case session data is maintained in memory and the only disadvantage of this approach (as I see it without going into specifics of your task) is that sometimes you might consider releasing the memory that is not needed at the moment. If you're using SQL Server to store session data, I'd choose another storage as serializing/deserializing your data set in this case will probably have an impact on the app performance.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on where you want to put the limit on the application.

Storing the data in memory will limit the application to a certain number of simultaneous users.

Getting the data from the database each time will lower the number of requests that the application can handle per second.

As with any optimisation, you should only optimise when you know what the need is, so I would suggest that you just get the data from the database, and add caching when there actually is a need for it.